# Mysql を使ったデータベース PHPの実行結果をhtmlファイルとして書き出したいです

Tags: php, mysql

データベースはMysqlを使っていますがPHPの実行結果をhtmlファイルとして書き出したいのですが `echo "<li class='active'><a href='special.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";`の`special.php?page={$i}'>{$i}`ができません！！
例えば：`{$i}`が12の場合：`special.php?page={$i}'>{$i}をspecial.html/12.html`のようにしたいです！！誰かご教授くださいませ！！

下記はテスト環境から本番環境にphpファイルを自動的にHTMLファイルに書き出すプログラムです：
syc.php

```
$url = "http://test.local/index.php";
$buff = file_get_contents($url);
$fname ="http://product/test.html";

$fhandle = fopen($fname, "w");
fwrite($fhandle, $buff);
fclose($fhandle);
?>
```

下記はテスト環境でのindex.phpファイルです：

```
<?php require_once("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/db.php"); ?>
<?php  require_once("includes/navigation.php"); ?>
<div id="main" role="main">
    <section class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li data-thumb="/slider/images"><a href="/"><img src="images" /></a></li></ul>
    </section>
</div>
       <ul>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test  ORDER BY test_id DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $test_id = $row['test_id'];
            $test_title = $row['test_title'];
            $test_image = $row['test_image'];
?>    
    <li><a href="#"><img src="./images/<?php echo $test_image; ?>" alt="</a><a href="#"><?php echo $test_title;?></li> 
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

下記はincludes/navigation.phpファイルです：

```
<?php
   ob_start();
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php  
            $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
            $cat_query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_query)){
                    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
                    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
                    $category_id = $row['category_id'];
                    }
                ?>
                <?php echo "<li><a　href='http://test.local/camera/index.php'>カメラ</a></li>"; ?>
                <?php echo "<li><a href='http://test.local/iphone/'>携帯</a></li>"; ?>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

下記はcameraカテゴリ-の一覧を表示するindex.phpファイルです：

camera/index.php

```
<?php require_once("includes/db.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/navigation.php"); ?></div>
<div class="container"> 
<?php  
    $per_page = 15;
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    } else{
        $page = "";
    }
    if($page == "" || $page == 1){
        $page_1 = 0;
    }else{
        $page_1 = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;
    }
    $count = "SELECT * FROM camera";
    $find_count = mysqli_query($db, $count);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($find_count);
    $count = ceil($count / $per_page);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM camera ORDER BY camera_id DESC LIMIT $page_1, $per_page";
    $camera_query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($camera_query)){
        $camera_id = $row['camera_id'];
        $camera_name = $row['camera_name'];
?>
<div>
    <a href="camera.php?camera_id=<?php echo $camera_id; ?>">
    <h3><?php echo $camera_name; ?></h3>
</div>
<ul class="pager">
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
        if($i == $page){
            echo "<li class='active'><a href='camera.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
        }else{
            echo "<li><a href='camera.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

こちらは詳細ページのcamera.php

```
<?php require_once("includes/db.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/navigation.php"); ?>
<section>
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['camera_id'])){
        $the_id = $_GET['camera_id'];
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM camera WHERE camera_id = $the_id";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $camera_id = $row['camera_id'];
        $camera_name= $row['camera_name'];
?>
<div><?php echo $camera_name; ?></div>
```

Comment: もう少し問題を整理して、最小限のコードで問題を表現するようにした方が良いと思います。
さらに、「xxできない」という現象だけだと余計本当の課題が見えにくくなります。実現するためのコードがわからないのか、なんらかエラーが発生していてそれが解消できないのか、できないにしても色々あります。
それも含めて、必要最小限のコードにすると、ご自身でも問題が整理できてくるかと思います。

Comment: データベースはMysqlを使っていますがPHPの実行結果をhtmlファイルとして書き出したいのですが echo "{$i}";のspecial.php?page={$i}'>{$i}ができません！！例えば：{$i}が12の場合：special.php?page={$i}'>{$i}をspecial.html/12.htmlのようにしたいです！！

Comment: コメントで追記するのはやめましょう。質問本文を編集して問題点を明確にしたり、行いたいことについて簡潔にまとめるように指摘されているかと思います。また、行内でコードブロックを作成したい場合はグレイヴアクセント(`)を使用して括ると良いです。

Answer (score 0):

出力に絞って回答すると
パスの参照がおかしいのではないかと

```
<?php
$url = "http://test.local/index.php";
$buff = file_get_contents($url);
//fopenの参照は相対パス、もしくはルートからの絶対パスです
$fname ="./test.html";
$fname ="/var/www/html/test.html";

$fhandle = fopen($fname, "w");
fwrite($fhandle, $buff);
fclose($fhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Myakuさん：ありがとうございます！！相対パスでは<?php require_once("includes/navigation.php"); ?>の内容が書き出せなかったんです！！ルートの絶対パスでやる方法もありますね！！勉強になりました。